# Get look from player inside of the game to apply to a dummy

Tags: lua, roblox

I have tried countless of things but none work. A little better explanation.

I want a Dummy to get the look of the player (its a 1 player game). The best i have being able to do is get the head right but nothing else.

```
wait(2)
local hum = script.Parent
local players = game:GetService("Players")

for _, player in pairs(players:GetPlayers())  do
    b = player.Character.Humanoid.GetAppliedDescription
    hum:ApplyDescription(b)
    
end
```

Comment: provide your code. show what you have tried

Comment: This is what i have right now

Comment: I get the error "Unablet to cast value to object"

Comment: Changed some stuff and now only the head works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetAppliedDescription` is a function call. So you need to do:

```lua
b = player.Character.Humanoid:GetAppliedDescription()
```

Comment: No doesnt work like that wihout the humanoid being refrenced directly. Like the dummy but i dont refrence the players dummy before i start to apply